# Need help for mySQL query for my forum dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[My forum Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I6GN.jpg)

I got 2 tables forum_category and forum_topics. the problem is that the
the latest post is not accurate... I don't know the query for it.

Can anyone help me ?

The sample output is on the image ... I'm using codeigniter for that

- The `category` contains columns id,name,desc
- `topic` contains of columns of id,subject,desc,date_posted and posted_by

Query:

```
$select =   array(
            'forum_category.f_cat_name',
            'forum_category.f_cat_id',
            'forum_category.f_cat_desc',
            'forum_topic.topic_subject as last_posted',
            'max(forum_topic.date_posted) as last_date_posted',
            'max(forum_topic.posted_by) as last_posted_by',
            'count(forum_topic.topic_id) as total'
        );  
        $query=$this->db
    ->select($select)
    ->from('forum_category')
    ->where('f_cat_type',1)
        ->where('f_cat_status',1)

    ->join('forum_topic','forum_topic.f_cat_id = forum_category.f_cat_id','inner')
    ->group_by('forum_category.f_cat_id')
    ->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: Luckily, this question is asked and answered endlessly

Comment: Welcome to SO. A good question might contain everything in Text, especially when you are asking for help,

Comment: @Strawberry, yeah im looking for it, but it makes it more complicated coz we dont have the same structure. Hope u understand.

Answer (score 0):

Join clause should come before where clause.

try this,

```
$query=$this->db
->select($select)
->from('forum_category')
->join('forum_topic','forum_topic.f_cat_id = forum_category.f_cat_id','inner')  
->where('f_cat_type',1)
->where('f_cat_status',1)
->group_by('forum_category.f_cat_id')
->get();
return $query->result();
```